# CLLocationManager and CLGeoCoder

Tags: xamarin.ios, cllocationmanager, clgeocoder

I want to use coordinate of the actual location (CLLocationManager) to reverse geocoding (CLGeoCoder).
I have this code:

```
        locationMgr = new CLLocationManager();
        locationMgr.DesiredAccuracy = CLLocation.AccuracyNearestTenMeters;
        locationMgr.DistanceFilter = 10;
        locationMgr.UpdatedLocation += (object sender, CLLocationUpdatedEventArgs e) => {
            Task.latitude = e.NewLocation.Coordinate.Latitude;
            Task.longitude = e.NewLocation.Coordinate.Longitude;
            locationMgr.StopUpdatingLocation();
        };

        btnLocation = new UIBarButtonItem(UIImage.FromFile("Icons/no-gps.png"), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (s,e) => {
            if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled) { 
                    locationMgr.StartUpdatingLocation();

                    geoCoder = new CLGeocoder();
                    geoCoder.ReverseGeocodeLocation(new CLLocation(Task.latitude, Task.longitude), (CLPlacemark[] place, NSError error) => {
                        adr = place[0].Name+"\n"+place[0].Locality+"\n"+place[0].Country;
                        Utils.ShowAlert(XmlParse.LocalText("Poloha"), Task.latitude.ToString()+"\n"+Task.longitude.ToString()+"\n\n"+adr);
                    });
            }
            else {
                Utils.ShowAlert(XmlParse.LocalText("PolohVypnut"));
            }
        });
```

Because UpdatedLocation() take some seconds, input of ReverseGeocodeLocation() is Task.latitude=0 and Task.longitude=0.

How can I wait for right values (Task.latitude, Task.longitude) before ReverseGoecodeLocation()?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: wait until the UpdatedLocation event fires before starting your Reverse Geocode lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Your geocoder's `ReverseGeocodeLocation` method is called before the `CLLocationManager` gets a location.

Calling `StartUpdatingLocation` does not mean that the `UpdatedLocation` event will be triggered immediately. Furthermore, if you are on iOS 6, `UpdatedLocation` will never be triggered. Use the `LocationsUpdated` event instead.

Example:

```
locationManager.LocationsUpdated += (sender, args) => {

    // Last item in the array is the latest location
    CLLocation latestLocation = args.Locations[args.Locations.Length - 1];
    geoCoder = new CLGeocoder();
    geoCoder.ReverseGeocodeLocation(latestLocation, (pl, er) => {

        // Read placemarks here

    });

};
locationManager.StartUpdatingLocation();
```